# Fullcalendar vue 3 The inferred type of 'default' cannot be named without a reference to

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, fullcalendar

Hi i'm trying to impl Fullcalendar.io into my vue3 app. I have installed all the necessary packages/plugins.
All the code works when i'm running the app. But in VS Code im getting a error from typescript, see below:

The inferred type of 'default' cannot be named without a reference to '../../../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/internal-common'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

[image]

Does Fullcalendar recommend a specific version of typescript to be run or where does this error come from?

My different versions:
"typescript": "~5.0.4", "vite": "^4.3.4", "vue": "^3.2.47",

And Fullcalendar versions:
"@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/vue3": "^6.1.8",

EDIT:
I have set up an codesandbox here:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-golick-5cpp59?file=/src/components/Calendar.vue)

Unclear for me if its the same problem, its a different error message, but looks like its the same package e.g "@fullcalendar/core/internal-common" that is failing.

Comment: I recommend you replicate this issue in a code sandbox, then share the link in your question. Alternatively, go and find a functional code sandbox with the vite, ts, vue3, and full calendar and check what versioning it's using. You can play with it and adapt your code to make it work.

Comment: I have now added a codesandbox! Thanks. @EliezerVerasVargas

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party here, but I found this issue to be caused by using the non typescript example. I was using typescript and there is a specific example that includes pulling in several modules from the core including CalendarOptions. After following the correct example it works fine for me.
Example: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/blob/main/vue3-typescript/src/DemoApp.vue